# How to get PySpark working on Google Cloud Composer

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I found Google Cloud Composer to be quite promising managed Apache Airflow service, but I couldn't figure out how to use Cloud Composer to execute pipeline with PySpark code. I am able to install other Python packages e.g. Pandas and use Cloud Composer just fine.

Any pointer is really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Composer is used to schedule pipelines.

Thus for running PySpark code in Cloud Composer you need to create a Dataproc Cluster as PySpark jobs run in Dataproc clusters.
In the DAG, using [DataprocCreateClusterOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#create-a-cluster) you can schedule to create a Dataproc Cluster. After the Cluster is created, you can submit your PySpark job to the Dataproc cluster using the [DataprocSubmitJobOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#submit-a-job-to-a-cluster). To submit a job to the cluster you need to provide a job source file.
You can refer to the below piece of code for reference.

**PySpark code:**

```
import pyspark
from operator import add
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

data = sc.parallelize(list("Hello World"))
counts = data.map(lambda x: 
    (x, 1)).reduceByKey(add).sortBy(lambda x: x[1],
     ascending=False).collect()

for (word, count) in counts:
    print("{}: {}".format(word, count))
```

**DAG Code:**

```
import os
import datetime
from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import (
   DataprocCreateClusterOperator,
   DataprocSubmitJobOperator
)
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.dataproc import DataprocJobSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

PROJECT_ID = "give your project id"
CLUSTER_NAME =  "your dataproc cluster name that you want to create"
REGION = "us-central1"
ZONE = "us-central1-a"
PYSPARK_URI = "GCS location of your PySpark Code i.e gs://[input file]"

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

# Cluster definition
# [START how_to_cloud_dataproc_create_cluster]

CLUSTER_CONFIG = {
   "master_config": {
       "num_instances": 1,
       "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
       "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
   },
   "worker_config": {
       "num_instances": 2,
       "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
       "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
   },
}

with models.DAG(
   "dataproc",

   schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
   default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

   # [START how_to_cloud_dataproc_create_cluster_operator]
   create_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
       task_id="create_cluster",
       project_id=PROJECT_ID,
       cluster_config=CLUSTER_CONFIG,
       region=REGION,
       cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
   )

   PYSPARK_JOB = {
   "reference": {"project_id": PROJECT_ID},
   "placement": {"cluster_name": CLUSTER_NAME},
   "pyspark_job": {"main_python_file_uri": PYSPARK_URI},
   }

   pyspark_task = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
       task_id="pyspark_task", job=PYSPARK_JOB, location=REGION, project_id=PROJECT_ID
   )

   create_cluster >>  pyspark_task
```