# Trigger a simple python script located inside a Google Cloud Platform bucket with program arguments using airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am new to airflow. I have a simple python script **my_python_script.py** located inside a GCP bucket. I would like to trigger this python script *with program arguments* using airflow.

My *airflow* python code somewhat looks like this:

```
import pytz
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocSubmitJobOperator
from pytz import timezone
from helper import help
import pendulum


config = help.loadJSON("batch/path/to/json")

executor_config = config["executor"]

common_task_args = {
    'owner': 'my_name',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': config["mailingList"],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'start_date': pendulum.datetime(2022, 4, 10, tz=time_zone),
    'executor_config': executor_config,
    'gcp_conn_id': config["connectionId"],
    'project_id': config["projectId"],
    'location': config["location"]
}

dag = DAG('my_dag',
          default_args=common_task_args,
          is_paused_upon_creation=True,
          catchup=False,
          schedule_interval=None)

simple_python_task = {
    "reference": {"project_id": config["projectId"]},
    "placement": {"cluster_name": config["clusterName"]},
    <TODO: initialise my_python_script.py script located on GCP bucket with program arguments>
}

job_to_be_triggered = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
    task_id="simple_python_task",
    job=simple_python_task,
    dag=dag
)

job_to_be_triggered
```

What am I supposed to do in the **TODO** section in the code snippet above? The idea is to trigger my_python_script.py script located in a GCP dataproc bucket [gs://path/to/python/script.py] with program arguments [to the python script].

*PS:* It is important for the python script to be on GCP.

Comment: What is your UseCase ? Why can't you put the script along with the source code of your DAG ? [Check the Doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html)

Comment: The use case is ensure all the python scripts located inside a GCP bucket. We then trigger them from airflow as and when necessary. As the code is quite dynamic [the python scripts], moving them to GCP will avoid unnecessary changes to the airflow script.

Comment: Yes, I did go through the doc posted by you earlier. Unfortunately, could not help me with what I was looking for. Hence, posted the query here.

Comment: If you're not using Cloud Composer, you can use [GCSFileTransformOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/gcs/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.gcs.GCSFileTransformOperator) and then execute the script locally. If you're using Composer, you can use [local folders](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket) the same way (and maybe move the files first).

Comment: So I am assuming there is no way to trigger a python script located on google cloud? [I do know for a fact as portrayed here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html that a pyspark script on GCP can be triggered from airflow]

Comment: You need to put the file on the dataproc cluster and then launch the operator with the correct filepath. Do you have a running cluster ?

Comment: @vdolez Yes I do have a running cluster. I already have the script on the dataproc cluster. What I am not aware of is how to run it from airflow.

Comment: The script path should not be inside a GCP Bucket but inside the Dataproc Cluster.

Comment: Can you try adding a python script file with the main parameter inside the function DataprocSubmitJobOperator? For example main= `gs://bucket/my-script.py`. For more information you can refer to this [document](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc/index.html?highlight=how%20use%20python%20file%20used%20gcs%20bucket#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc.DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator).

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT The link that you have shared is specific to a pyspark job is it not? Also, I did not come across any argument to specify the dataproc cluster related info, the way "DataprocSubmitJobOperator" has. Do you have a working example for "DataprocJobBaseOperator" by any chance?

Comment: @vdolez How do we trigger such a script if the script resides inside dataproc cluster?

Comment: Hi @mang4521, Can you please clarify which operator you want to use to submit the job? To use python script as per your requirement you can run pyspark job using `DataprocSubmitJobOperator` following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235616). Let me know if it’s helpful or not?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT I am fine with any operator as long as in is meant for a python script on dataproc [GCS]. As for the link shared by you, it again is pointing to a pyspark job rather than a plain python script. Thus, asking you there is a way to configure a plain python script rather than masquerading it as a pyspark script?

Comment: If you have to use the plain python script, you can make  use of `PythonOperator`,  `PythonVirtualenvOperator`, or you can also use [`BashOperator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610313/how-to-use-airflow-to-run-a-folder-of-python-files/41388139#41388139) to execute python files as a task.

Comment: Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Does not meet the requirements.